# Chrome keep asking me for a download location on Selenium Hub/Driver on Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download a couple of files in a test that are randomly generated on the back-end with a unique name

I use this preferences that I pass to the chrome driver both directly or in a selenium hub

```
CHROME_PREFERENCES = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
    "download.directory_upgrade": "true",
    "download.default_directory": "/mnt/hgfs/down/",
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1
}
```

But Chrome keeps asking me for the download location every time that I make the get call to the download URL from the driver, rendering the automation useless...

I also tried, using bool values as True / False instead of "true" / "false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
options = Options()
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.default_directory': download_dir,
        'download.directory_upgrage': True,
        'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
        }
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```

p.s. Sorry, i couldn't comment, so I ask here: How do you pass your preferences?

Comment: Just simplify the options to the config suggest... but the behavior is exactly the same... even remove the directory change

Comment: This config was correct, in the end, the problem itself was that the download dir was a hgfs partition that wasn't immediately available for the browser